# How to make a CSS responsive background img for a long one page website

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, background-image, responsive-images

I have tried for two days now to make the background img responsive for a mobile. It's a one long home page (around 8000px). The content of the whole page has a div parent "background_div". I have tried both, size cover or contain tags, the img gets over pixaleted, like it would be zoomed in, the content is responsive but the background img gives me a headache. I need it to recognize the device width, scale down and stay fixed not stretched along the 8000px long page. Can any one give me an idea whats wrong here?

```css
#background_div {
 background-image: url('home.jpg');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}

/*It just won't scale to the divice width and height*/
```

```html
<div id="background_div">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

Setting these to **cover** is going to stretch the image to fit the container, no matter how big it is.  That is what's causing your stretching.

Set them to **auto**, or don't set them at all, if you want the image to retain it's original size.

Comment: It works well on laptop, when minimizing to check if it's responsive, but now on my phone, it gets centered to middle and occupies only a small portion leaving most of the page white, I am new to responsive css, can you give me one more advice on how to get this done?

Comment: Found a decent solution, it needs a few small changes but seems like it's working,

Answer (score 0):

**CSS2**

If you need to make the image bigger, you must edit the image itself in an image editor.

If you use the img tag, you can change the size, but that would not give you the desired result if you need the image to be background for some other content (and it will not repeat itself like you seems to want)...

**CSS3 unleash the powers**

This is possible to do in CSS3 with background-size.

All modern browsers support this, so unless you need to support old browsers, this is the way to do it.

**Supported browsers:**

Mozilla Firefox 4.0+ (Gecko 2.0+), Microsoft Internet Explorer 9.0+, Opera 10.0+, Safari 4.1+ (webkit 532) and Chrome 3.0+.

```
#background_div {
    /* width: will stretch to width / height of element */
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```